# Safari - Content not displaying correctly, CSS position error?

Tags: html, css, safari, css-float, css-position

In safari and some other browsers, my footer isnt sticking correctly. It looks to me like it must be something todo with either positioning or float.

Would someone mind taking a look please? Have been pulling my hair out trying to solve this.

http://r.adamtoms.co.uk

Many Thanks!

Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another error that makes the footer stick correctly..

**You got**

```
/* W3C */
display: inline-flex;
```

**Fix**

```
/* Safari, Opera, and Chrome */
display: -webkit-inline-box;
```

**For moz**

```
/* Firefox */
display: -moz-inline-box;
```

Did test it and it works.

Comment: thanks Ray thats great. Would I add this in addition to the display:inline-flex; ?

Comment: You can do that yeah, I added mozilla just in case.

Comment: Hi @Rayf, I have some more issues with this. Now in win8 IE 11, the footer is appearing at the top of the page. Would you mind taking a look, cant figure out whats causing it?
r.adamtoms.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

If you put a

```
float:left;
```

on your footer it looks the same as in the other browsers.

Comment: feeling rather stupid... Thank you so much speetje33!